# Solidworks - Projected Curve is incomplete

Tags: solidworks, technical-drawing

-- *This issue might be due to a bug in SolidWorks 2014 SP2* --

I'm trying to route a water hose from one location to another without passing through a keepout area (the red box shown).

I am simply sweeping a circle (red sketch) along a Projected Curve defined by two orthogonal sketches, one on TOP (green curve) and one on FRONT (blue curve).

[image]

It's very nearly working, apart from that I cannot seem to persuade Solidworks to complete the Projected Curve.  It always seems to stop short of the final location.

Each of the two control curves begin and end with straight line segments that are tangent to the spline that governs the path.  I need these to get a nice, straight controlled entry/exit from the flat surfaces.

The control points begin and end at the same locations in space (projected onto their respective planes).

What am I doing wrong, that is preventing this curve from being completed?

Comment: Why not do this with a 3D Sketch/Spline? You'll need to provide more screenshots, or a copy of your files if you want diagnosis of what's causing the projected curve to not work in this specific instance, since it worked for me when I just tested it!

Comment: Because I want to know what's wrong with the way I'm using the "projected curves" feature.  I'm either missing some crucial step or it's a bug in SaladForks.

Comment: It's not a bug with SolidWorks - as I said, it works for me... [Proof.](https://i.imgur.com/C0MeXdz.png) Perhaps there's some discontinuity in your sketches or something? You could try creating a new sketch, and using the 'Fit Spline' Tool to create a continuous single curve that is in contiguous with the sketch you were trying to use. Then use those new sketches as the basis of your 'sketch on sketch' Projected Curve. Unfortunately without more information I can't answer your question ("What am I doing wrong...?").

Comment: I'm using SW 2014, which has a few issues, your version looks a lot more recent.  When I get back to work I'll try to find a minimum subset of sketch work that reproduces the problem.  That'll be easier to present here, I think.

Comment: Yes - I’m on the latest version. I can also test with 2015 SP4.0 later this evening, perhaps.

Comment: I'm starting to think it is a corner case bug in SW2014.  I'm having a hard time reproducing it with different geometry.  Flagging to close.

Comment: Your self-critical attitude is very positive, but I think this question doesn't deserve closure, what if others have later the same problem?

Comment: @peterh, fair enough, I've added a note to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a 3D Sketch Spline for creating your hose - this will more accurately model the natural shape that the hose would assume given the boundary conditions of perpendicular to the grey transparent block at the in/out positions. Let me know if you have any questions regarding this method:

[image: Gif showing how to use 3D Sketch Spline for Hose Creation[1]]

Comment: +1, accepted.  If it does turn out to be a bug in SW2014 then your answer solves the problem.  May I ask what screen capture software you use?  It does a good job of shrinking a SW session.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I used [LICEcap](https://www.cockos.com/licecap/) - I'm glad I was able to be of assistance!

Comment: Jonathan, your content is no longer available!!!! I wound up here while searching for answers to [my own questions](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48373/coiling-and-bending-pipe-in-3d-model?noredirect=1#comment87724_48373).   BTW, is it possible to do that projected line thing in the question in Inventor?

Comment: Ugh. That's annoying... Looks like Imgur .gif uploads don't have an infinite shelf life . It's 1) almost certainly possible in inventor, but 2) probably not the solution to your question, same as it wasn't here.