# Is there sufficient information to complete the bottom end?

Tags: solidworks, cad, technical-drawing, drawings, autodesk-inventor

**BACKGROUND**

Fresh of the heels of figuring out my "kinky" issues in [this question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48373/coiling-and-bending-pipe-in-3d-model/48424?noredirect=1#comment87818_48424) I thought I was fully prepared to deal with the following drawing titled [COILED PIPE 2](http://www.digipeer.de/index.php?media=DMA_FA_014_02628&size=3).  The drawing seemed rather straight forward and initially came across as a mirrored piece with slightly wider main coil.

The notes in German in the bottom right corner talk about passing a 7 mm diameter ball test and I believe a pressure test.

[image]

**PROBLEM**

I do not know if there is sufficient information to complete the bottom run out of the coil.  In the previous question I had a few more dimensions to work with.  Part of me is wondering if this is more of a give them the final position and general plan and let the fabricator decide what works best?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

I started out with a top view of the centerline path.  You will note that I made a WILD GUESS as a place holder for the 20 mm radius circular arc which is not dimensioned on the original drawing and may not even be a circle in this plane.

[image]

I then proceeded to attempt to draw the front view. At which point I hit a wall...then started banging my head against it...repeatedly.

[image]

So far the few things I have been holding on to are:

- In the top view the pipe remains in line with the main coil until it turns in.
- In the front view, the coil is shown as extending out to the quadrant, but in the top view is turns in before that.  This seems wrong to me.  Perhaps my 55 dimension should be eliminated.
- In the front view the bottom of the circular arc will finish with a horizontal tangent.
- In the front view the top of the circular arc will be tangent to the slope line from the uncoiled helix.  Problem is the unrolled location of the point of tangency and the location of the circle are not easily obvious as the circle needs to be shifted to the left some amount to account for the uncoiling.  Been struggling for a way to graphically figure this out to avoid rounding errors with the math method.

I also tried extruding the circular arc and projecting the helix's circle down on to it similar to the previous question to see if that would shed any light on things.  However, it only made me realize it was not going to give me the curve I needed AND the previous edge distance problem where the top view and front view are not lining up.

[image]

**QUESTION**

Is there enough information to draw this, or is it more of a case of get the main dimensioned part right (ie. main coil, and pipe end locations) and leave it up to the fabricator to figure out how to get from the pipe end to the main coil as long as the pipe generally line up like the drawing?

If there is sufficient information, what am I not picking up on?

Comment: Who is downvoting these questions? If you think the question could be improved, put a comment here to say why!

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Perhaps because it may be basic drawing practice covered in a text book ?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I did not realize there were down votes until this question.  I thought someone might have been getting tired of so many questions from the same person.  While I do admit I have asked a lot of questions, I am not asking them of every drawing (Completed 169 V2 drawings and 106 Example exercises).  Only ones where I get stuck or stumble.  Even after asking questions, I continue to dig or try different approaches.  Hence I was able to answer a few of my own questions.  But I agree, without constructive criticism to accompany a downvote, how does one improve a question.